# how to implement logical and on array length?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, logical-operators

I need to translate the matlab code

```
indexSelect0 = a.index1==0 & a.index2==wRange;
```

into a fast python style. My try is:

```
idx1=np.array(np.where(a['index2'][:,0]==wIndex2))
idx=np.array(np.where(a['index1'][:,0]==wIndex1))
indexSelect0 = ma.masked_array(idx,mask=[not (i in idx1[0,:]) for i in idx[0,:]])
```

but it takes a while as the array is pretty long (more than 5M of samples).

The problem can be stated as : I have an array of data that is composed of different observations. I have 2 indices that allow me to know where is what. But I am not able to find the right way to combine two options to filter the data.

Hope it is clear.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is your `a`? Is it dataframe? Could you provide sample data?

Comment: a is a dictionnary. Could it be easier if a is a dataframe ?

Answer (score 2):

For backup I found the answer. I thank Anton for having directed me to DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'index1': a['index1'][:,0].squeeze(), 'index2': a['index2'][:,0].squeeze(), 'data': x}
df= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
y = df[(df.index1==wIndex1) & (df.index2==wIndex2)]
```

So I use the DataFrame of the pandas module and the boolean operator for indexing and selecting the data (more here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html). It works fine : readable, simple for coding and much faster.

Answer (score 1):

The exact equivalent of your MATLAB, with the `struct` converted to a `dict`, is:

```
indexSelect0 = (a['index1'] == 0) & (a['index2'] == wRange)
```

On my 5-year-old laptop I was able to process 10 million samples in just a few seconds:

```
n = 10000000
a = {'index1': np.random.randint(0, 10, n), 'index2': np.random.randint(0, 10, n)}
wRange = 5
indexSelect0 = (a['index1'] == 0) & (a['index2'] == wRange)
```